# is there a way to capture stdout in Julia like capture.output() in R?

Tags: r, julia

In R, `capture.output()` can capture the output to `stdout` in an expression as a character vector, e.g.

```
> x = capture.output(print(1:10))
> x
[1] " [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10"
```

Is there an equivalent function in Julia?

Comment: What have you tried? At a guess, you change OUTPUT_STREAM, STDOUT and STDERR to something: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.1/stdlib/base/#i-o - there's IOBuffer which might give you an object you can write and read to...

Comment: ...Or not: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.julia.devel/10794

Comment: `OUTPUT_STREAM` has been removed in Julia 0.2; I have read the mailing list last night, and discussed under Westley's pull request (which was closed a few weeks ago)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Julia 0.2, there is now a way to capture standard output: you can call [redirect_stdout](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.redirect_stdout) to convert `STDOUT` into a pipe that you can read from.

This is mainly useful to capture output from external C libraries.   As Stefan mentioned, most Julia I/O functions accept an `io` argument that allows you to print to an arbitrary destination, such as a string buffer.

Comment: Thanks! This looks closer to `capture.output()` in R.

Answer (score 4):

Standard library functions should all accept an optional IO-typed first argument that will be printed to if provided but otherwise will default to STDOUT. In that case, you can use `sprint(io->f(io,...))` to capture what's printed to a string. If the functions haven't been written to print to a given IO object, then there isn't a way to redirect the output.

Comment: thanks! your last sentence explains why I asked this question; more under https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/3044

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you are after, but if you are trying to bring `knitr` to `julia` then awesome!

The Gadfly package has weave, which does some of this.

Check out https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/weave.jl#L19

and

https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/weave.jl#L423

I've been using it in https://github.com/jverzani/Weave.jl to make self-grading quizzes from markdown.

Comment: I'm working on bringing `julia` to `knitr`; the opposite way is much more difficult for me :) I was not aware that this had been done in Gadfly. That looks cool! So the key seems to be overriding the `print()` and `println()` functions in a sandbox. Interesting. I guess this is what I want.

Comment: A better answer [might be coming](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/3044) in the future versions of Julia, and this answer is satisfactory enough at the moment.